# python version for C for loop

Tags: python, loops

Can anyone show me the python forloop style for this kind of C forloop

```
for (end_timeout=1, i=0; i<TIME_OUT; i++)
    {
        bit = Inp32(status_register) & (1 << PtrClk);

        if ( ( bit >> PtrClk ) == 1 )
        {
            end_timeout = 0;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Based on your names, you are best off not doing any sort of timeout or timing code with for-loops and `sleep`, because it is very easy to desync. Better would be to poll the system clock. For more info on `range`, do `help(range)`. There is no need to use `xrange` unless you're still using python2. Sidenote: If you are iterating over a list, you can do `for i,value in enumerate(myList):...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
end_timeout = 1
for i in xrange(TIME_OUT):
    ...
```

This will start the loop with `i == 0`. Use `xrange(n, TIME_OUT)` if you want to start with `i == n`.

See the documentation for[`xrange`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#xrange).

Comment: Since you don't know if the OP is using python 2 or 3, I wouldn't use xrange.

Comment: @Voo: Indeed I don't, but in case they're using python 2, I'd prefer `xrange` over `range`.

Answer (score 5):

```
end_timeout = 1
for i in range(TIME_OUT):
    pass
```

Answer (score 1):

```
end_timeout = 1
for i in range(TIME_OUT):
    # ...your code
```